# Cassandra - data loss on a dead node with CF = 1

Tags: cassandra

I'm a newbie to Cassandra and have a question on the commit log which is configured to use periodic mode (10 seconds).

Suppose we have a node that processes a request with CF = 1 and RF = 3. If the node is in a state in which the commit log has not been flushed to disk and replication of the data is also pending, would we loose data if the node crashes in this state?

Another follow-up question, which node is responsible for replicating the data on other nodes based on RF=3? Is is the coordinator node or some other node which processes the request depending on consistency level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think following link might be of use to you:
https://www.ecyrd.com/cassandracalculator/

Yes, data loss is possible in this scenario because data would not reach other nodes, so no copies exist. As if the data was not there. The thing is this window is actually quite small because with RF 3 the other nodes will receive the insert within the milliseconds (Unless there is some really heavy load on the node).

All of the RF requests (per single client request) are handled by the coordinator. Also if the node might not be there when the coordinator needs to replicate it stores the data in a hint.

So to sum it up yes data loss is possible but the probability is really small.

Comment: follow-up question just for the sake of understanding. If the data node and the coordinator node are different, and the data node which acked for CF=1 goes down/crashes before commit log is flushed, there are chances the data would be replicated to remaining two data nodes since coordinator node has already sent the replication request. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks, Marko.
@Chris - Both answers are correct. I'm picking this one mainly because of additional information.

Answer (score 2):

With CL=ONE when a coordinator crashes and goes down uncleanly there is a window where data loss is possible before the mutation is sent to replicas and commit log is flushed. Its pretty small window and unlikely but if its a concern use local quorum or batch mode.

The coordinator will send data to all replicas and store hints for whatever hasn't acked.